# How to find a struct list item

Tags: c++, algorithm, struct, lambda, find

I have a list of struct that is described below:

```
struct Files
{
    string id;
    string path;
    string chksum;
};
```

And a variable that contains a list of this struct that describes a file list with the fields `id`, `path` and `chksum`.

```
list<Files> myFiles;
```

I need to implement an function that searches if a determined filename is present in my list.

I tried to use the `find_if` algorithm but I am getting very strange errors, and I am not sure how to implement this efficiently.

```
string filename = "mytext.txt";

auto match = std::find_if(myFiles.cbegin(), myFiles.cend(), [] (const Files& s) {
  return s.path == filename;
});

if (match != myFiles.cend()) 
{
    cout << "omg my file was found!!! :D";
}
else
{
    cout << "your file is not here :(";
}
```

Comment: _I tried to use the `find_if`_... Can you add that code, too?

Comment: sure... i edited to include my tried code

Comment: For future reference, try to include as much detail in your questions as possible: What IDE are you using?; What is the text of the errors you are getting?; etc.

Comment: *Strange errors* is not a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `filename` to the capture list of the lambda:

```
string filename = "mytext.txt";

auto match = std::find_if(myFiles.cbegin(), myFiles.cend(), [filename] (const Files& s) {
    return s.path == filename;
});

if (match != myFiles.cend()) 
{
    cout << "omg my file was found!!! :D";
}
else
{
    cout << "your file is not here :(";
}
```

Comment: Or simply `[=]`, though `[&]` (or `[&filename]`) might make more sense to avoid making a copy of the string

Comment: Yes that worked OK but please edit the post and replace the simbols.cend() to myFiles.cend()

Comment: @RemyLebeau I thought about mentioning capture defaults or filename by reference but decided not to muddy the issue; especially with short strings.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the variable `filename` is declared in a block scope. In this case you have to capture it. It is better to capture it by reference as for example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Files
{
    std::string id;
    std::string path;
    std::string chksum;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<Files> myFiles = { { "10", "mytext.txt", "10" } };

    std::string filename = "mytext.txt";

    auto match = std::find_if( std::cbegin( myFiles ), std::cend( myFiles ), 
                               [&] ( const Files &s ) 
                               {
                                    return s.path == filename;
                               } );

    if ( match != std::cend( myFiles ) ) 
    {
        std::cout << "omg my file was found!!! :D";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "your file is not here :(";
    }
}
```

Otherwise if the variable filename is declared in a namespace you can use the lambda as is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Files
{
    std::string id;
    std::string path;
    std::string chksum;
};

std::string filename = "mytext.txt";

int main()
{
    std::list<Files> myFiles = { { "10", "mytext.txt", "10" } };


    auto match = std::find_if( std::cbegin( myFiles ), std::cend( myFiles ), 
                               [] ( const Files &s ) 
                               {
                                    return s.path == filename;
                               } );

    if ( match != std::cend( myFiles ) ) 
    {
        std::cout << "omg my file was found!!! :D";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "your file is not here :(";
    }
}
```